# Expression Trees and Nullable Types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I've been playing around with Expression Trees.  I have the following simple method that performs a query by dynamically creating an Expression Tree.  ItemType is a nullable int in the database, *and also in the EF entity class*.  For some reason though the query throws the error of

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   binary operator Equal  is not defined
>   for the types
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and
>   'System.Int32'.

I don't think I'm asking EF to convert anything.  I've got my parameter defined as `int?`, which is what I thought it should be.

Note, I've looked at this

[Working with nullable types in Expression Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871989/working-with-nullable-types-in-expression-trees)

But this guy is trying to pass in his nullable int value typed as object, which EF I guess has problems with.  I'm actually declaring this as the right type *ab initio*.

```
   public void GetResultCollection<T>() {
        MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
        var result = db.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeof(T).Name + "s"));

        int? ItemTypeValue = 1;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "ItemType"),
                Expression.Constant(ItemTypeValue)),
            param);

        var list = result.Where(lambda).ToList();
    }
```

**EDIT**

I've also tried  `ItemTypeValue.Value`  -  same error

Comment: shouldn't it be Expression.Constant(ItemTypeValue.Value)?

Comment: Good idea, but no, same error

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you need to convert it

```
var right = Expression.Constant(ItemTypeValue , typeof(int?))
....

 var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "ItemType"),
                right),
            param);
```