# Why is a conversion necessary in Expression Trees

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067120/expression-trees-and-nullable-types) I asked 5 minutes ago, it's clear that the following code throws an exception, stating that

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   binary operator Equal is not defined
>   for the types
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and
>   'System.Int32'.

Code

```
public static void GetResultCollection<T>() {
        AccrualTrackingEntities db = new AccrualTrackingEntities();
        var result = db.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeof(T).Name + "s"));

        int? ItemTypeValue = 1;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "ProcInstId"),
                Expression.Constant(ItemTypeValue)),
            param);

        var list = result.Where(lambda).ToList();
    }
```

This code, however, with the type explicitly listed in `Expression.Constant` does work

```
class Program {
    public static void GetResultCollection<T>() {
        AccrualTrackingEntities db = new AccrualTrackingEntities();
        var result = db.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("[{0}]", typeof(T).Name + "s"));

        int? ItemTypeValue = 1;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "ProcInstId"),
                Expression.Constant(ItemTypeValue, typeof(int?))),
            param);

        var list = result.Where(lambda).ToList();
    }
```

The question is, *why* is `Expression.Constant` not able to convert implicitly from `int?` to ... `int?`

Comment: you could create your own extension where you can get the type and if it is nullable, etc. then use the Expression.Constant(Object, Type) with the discovered type

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Expression trees work at a lower level to normal source code - you can think of them as working at the level of the *output* of the compiler rather than the *input*. So while there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `int?` in C#, that conversion has to be represented in IL whenever the compiler uses it for a normal method... so it also has to be present in an expression tree representation.

Having said that, your example is somewhat unclear, given that you're trying to use an `int` (namely `ItemTypeValue.Value`) as a value for an `int?` constant, and we don't know what the type of the `ItemType` property is either.

A short but *complete* example of what you'd expect to work would really help.

EDIT: Okay, I think I'm with you now. The problem is that if you use

```
int? foo = 1;
Expression.Constant(foo);
```

then that calls [`Expression.Constant(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349084.aspx) which boxes the value of `foo`. At that point, `Expression.Constant` can't tell it was originally an `int?`, because it's now a boxed `int`. That's just the way .NET boxing works:

```
int? foo = 1;
object o = foo;
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType()); // Prints System.Int32
```

That overload of `Expression.Constant` determines the overall type of the expression from the value that it's given - so it creates an `int` expression, whereas you really want an `int?` expression.

In order to maintain the type information properly, you have to use the overload which allows you to specify the type:

```
int? foo = 1;
Expression.Constant(foo, typeof(int?));
```

It's still not entirely clear from your question which code works and which doesn't, but hopefully that'll help...

Comment: It's up.  I worded the original question poorly.  The way I had it, it was indeed trying to convert from int to int?  My original question should have been a straight shot from int? to int?

Comment: I changed the original question's text so it makes more sense.  Now it's got Expression.Constant(ItemValueType, int?) where ItemValueType is declared as int? (which I would think would be superfluous)  

If I had known you were in the neighborhood I would have triple-checked before posting :-)

Comment: @Adam: You still haven't told us what the type of "ItemType" is. That's why I was hoping for a *complete* example - a console app we can compile and run.

Comment: It's int? in the database, and in the entity.  That's why this is so confusing to me.

Comment: @Adam: Okay, so a constant of type `int?` should work, but a constant of type `int` won't. I think I'm with you now...

Comment: And I've replicated this with another database.  Another int? refuses to be searched with an expression.constant unless I explicitly specify the type, even if the variable I pass in is explicitly declared as int?

Comment: Brilliant as always, thanks Jon.  I will clean up my question to make things crystal clear (for internet posterity).  Did you get anything more than 15 from this Q, or are you already maxed out?

Comment: @Adam: Just the 15, but that's fine. Glad it helped :)