# Linq to Moq - Nullable Types

Tags: vb.net, linq, unit-testing, moq

I am writing a unit test and in it trying to setup a simple generic list containg mocks of an entity class...

```
Dim schedules = New List(Of Schedule) From
     {
         Mock.Of(Of Schedule)(Function(s) s.ActiveFrom = "2010-01-01" AndAlso
                                          s.ActiveUntil = New DateTime?("2110-01-01"))
     }
```

`Schedule.ActiveFrom` is a `Date` and `Schedule.ActiveUntill` is a `Nullable(Of Date)`.

When i run the unit test i get the following error message...

> The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable[System.Boolean] >and System.Boolean

I'm stumped; Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't of much help to your VB Unit test, but the C# equivalent works just fine:

```
 var schedules = new List<Schedule>
 {
    Mock.Of<Schedule>(
    s => s.ActiveFrom == new DateTime(2010, 01, 01) 
       && s.ActiveUntil == new Nullable<DateTime>(new DateTime(2110, 01, 01)))
 };

 Assert.IsTrue((schedules.Count == 1) && 
     schedules.Single(_ => (_.ActiveFrom == new DateTime(2010, 01, 01))
     && (_.ActiveUntil == new DateTime(2110, 01, 01))) != null);
```

It also isn't related to the implicit comparison of `DateTime` to `DateTime?` either as careful unpacking of the `DateTime?` also fails:

```
 AndAlso If(Not s.ActiveUntil.HasValue, False, 
            s.ActiveUntil.Value = New DateTime("2110-01-01")
```

I believe the issue may relate to [Mock.Of's usage](https://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/Linq/Mock.cs) of parsed `Expressions` during construction of the mock from the predicate provided - possibly there is nuance in VB which [wasn't considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798570/experiences-using-moq-with-vb-net).

If so, and assuming you don't want to change your unit tests to C#, you may need to either need to [build the Expressions by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067120/expression-trees-and-nullable-types) to get the `Mock.Of(predicate)` goodness to work, or revert to old style creation of your Mock / Fake objects:

```
  Dim scheduleMock As New Mock(Of Schedule)
  scheduleMock.SetupGet(Function(s) s.ActiveFrom).Returns("2010-01-01")
  scheduleMock.SetupGet(Function(s) s.ActiveUntil).Returns(New DateTime?("2110-01-01"))
  Dim schedules = New List(Of Schedule) From
       {
           scheduleMock.Object
       }

  Assert.IsTrue(schedules.Count = 1)
  Assert.IsTrue(schedules.First.ActiveFrom = "2010-01-01" 
                AndAlso schedules.First.ActiveUntil = "2110-01-01")
```

Comment: I believe you are correct, and I have gone back to the old style mock creation. The following works: `dim sched = Mock.Of(Of Schedule)() Mock.Get(sched).SetupProperty(Function(s) s.ActiveUntil, New Date?("2110-01-01"))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you actually have two different types.  VB can't handle that.  So you want to trap the nullable portion and if it is null, return a straight boolean.

One thing you can do is change:

```
s.ActiveUntil = New DateTime?("2110-01-01")
```

to

```
if(s.ActiveUntil is Nothing, FALSE, s.ActiveUntil = New DateTime?("2110-01-01"))
```

This way, if the field is null, a simple boolean is returned, and if it is not null, you can return the boolean results of the compare.