# Force convert DateTimeOffset to Nullable<DateTimeOffset>

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write a function that dynamically builds a LINQ query expression. I am unable to build an `Equals` expression that compares a `DateTimeOffset` to a `DateTimeOffset?` (`Expression.Equal` complains that the types can't by compared), nor I am able to convert a `DateTimeOffset` to a `DateTimeOffset?` to make `Expression.Equal` work, because `DateTimeOffset` cannot be converted to a `DateTimeOffset?` no matter what conversion strategy I use.

MyEntity.cs:

```
public class MyEntity {
    public DateTimeOffset? DeliverOn;
}
```

Main.cs:

```
public void Test {
    IQueryable<MyEntity> MyEntityList = Enumerable.Empty<MyEntity>().AsQueryable();
    DateTimeOffset? dt1 = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, TimeSpan.Zero);
    var expr = WhereEquals(MyEntityList, t => t.DeliverOn, dt1);
}
```

ExpressionBuilder.cs:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereEquals<TSource, TValue>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector, TValue value) {
    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(Expression.Equal(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), selector.Parameters));
}
```

Throws: ``` System.InvalidOperationException: 'The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable``1[System.DateTimeOffset]' and 'System.DateTimeOffset'.' ```

Even though `dt1` is a `DateTimeOffset?` at compile-time, at runtime, C# thinks `dt1` is a `DateTimeOffset`. I can I solve this?

I have tried:

- `DateTimeOffset? dt1 = (DateTimeOffset?)new DateTimeOffset(2018, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, TimeSpan.Zero);`
- `DateTimeOffset? dt1 = (DateTimeOffset?)(object)new DateTimeOffset(2018, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, TimeSpan.Zero);`
- `DateTimeOffset? dt1 = (DateTimeOffset?)Convert.ChangeType(new DateTimeOffset(2018, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, TimeSpan.Zero), typeof());`

However dt1 is still a `DateTimeOffset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the overload `Expression.Constant(Object, Type)` to specify the type of the value to use in comparison.

Without specifying the type, `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>` is being unwrapped to simply `DateTimeOffset`.

```
void Main()
{
    //IQueryable<MyEntity> MyEntityList = Enumerable.Empty<MyEntity>().AsQueryable();
    var MyEntityList = new List<MyEntity>();
    MyEntityList.Add(new MyEntity { DeliverOn = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, TimeSpan.Zero) });
    DateTimeOffset? dt1 = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, TimeSpan.Zero);
    var expr = WhereEquals<MyEntity, DateTimeOffset?>(MyEntityList.AsQueryable(), t => t.DeliverOn, (DateTimeOffset?)dt1);
    Console.WriteLine($"{expr.Count()} item(s) found");

    // Output:
    // selector.GetType() is System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[UserQuery + MyEntity, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]]]
    // typeof(TValue) is System.Nullable`1[System.DateTimeOffset]
    // value.GetType() is System.DateTimeOffset
    // 1 item(s) found
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public DateTimeOffset? DeliverOn;
}

public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereEquals<TSource, TValue>(IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector, TValue value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"selector.GetType() is {selector.GetType()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"typeof(TValue) is {typeof(TValue)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"value.GetType() is {value.GetType()}");
    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(Expression.Equal(selector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))), selector.Parameters));
}
```

Related, although the accepted answer uses `Expression.Convert()` which I think is unnecessary.

[Working with nullable types in Expression Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871989/working-with-nullable-types-in-expression-trees)